# Automation : Typing into input field throws error

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am trying to automate [this website](https://passport.yandex.com/registration/mail). The captcha field in the website seems to have some mechanism by which it detects that the input has been automated. I am using the below code to send keys to the captcha input.

```
driver.find_element_by_id('captcha').send_keys(captcha_solution)
```

I observed that even though the text is visible on the text field, the `value` attribute of the the element is still null as shown below

[image]

There are the following two events tied to the input field:

```
function invalid(e, t) {
  if (h._enabled) {
    var n = d.getPooled(e, t);
    try {
      c.batchedUpdates(p, n)
    } finally {
      d.release(n)
    }
  }
}
function onChange() {
  var e = this.__base;
  this.__base = a.__base;
  var t = r.apply(this, arguments);
  return this.__base = e, t
}
```

When I remove the input and type it with my keyboard, the `value` attribute does get set as shown below

[image]

So how would I go about fixing this issue. I also tried setting the `value` by javascript, but the same issue exists.

Comment: Just tested, the value of input id="capcha" is till updated normally on my side. I'm not sure what is your issue?

Comment: @Lee which browser? I tried it with both Chrome and Firefox, same issue exists

Comment: @MohitBhasi You should share exception details.

Comment: @MohitBhasi so this worked for me : $(".captcha-wrapper .form__field.form__field_filled .textinput.textinput_theme_normal.textinput_size_m #captcha[name='captcha'][type='text']").val('123'), use selenium's browser.execute_script to execute this Jquery, let us know if it works

Comment: @IshitaShah there were no exceptions thrown

Comment: @rs007 hey, thanks! this does work!

Comment: @MohitBhasi  cool, glad i was able to help out!, I will post this as an answer, kindly accept if it worked for you.

Comment: try sending one letter in one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this worked for me :

```
$(".captcha-wrapper .form__field.form__field_filled .textinput.textinput_theme_normal.textinput_size_m #captcha[name='captcha'][type='text']").val('123'),
```

use selenium's browser.execute_script to execute this Jquery, let us know if it works